# Clicking followup flag on outlook now deletes instead of marks complete

Tags: microsoft-outlook

For years, to mark a message's followup flag as "complete," I would click the followup flag and it would change to a green checkmark and everything was fine. Starting in the last few hours, clicking on the followup flag moves the mail item to the trash! To change the flag to complete I have to right-click the flag, scroll, scroll the fly-out window, and select Mark Complete.

How do I change it back to left-click on flag changes flag to "complete"?

Outlook 2016. Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: Do you have an Outlook Rule in place that deletes email?  You may need to change that.

Comment: Flagging an item complete in Outlook does not delete it in a default configuration. Something has been modified in your Outlook profile. Can you tell us what changes have been made?

Comment: 1. I have not made any new rules. Non of my rules send things to the trash

Comment: 2. If I hover over the follow up flag in the inbox, a tip appears that says "Click to delete the item." So it appear this is some built-in function  (feature) that somehow got triggered.

Comment: 3. The quick click for Follow UP flags is set to "Complete"

Comment: Make sure you have a good backup of your email, delete the Outlook Profile (Control Panel, Mail), uninstall Office 2016, restart, install Office 2016, patch fully, make a new email account and test again

Comment: If you accidentally re-size your columns and squish the last column to the end - you're putting the Flag column over the delete button (that you can't actually see) . Please try resizing your outlook and make sure the flag and delete buttons are no longer stacked on top of one another.

Comment: Aidan--you're a genius!

Comment: I can't vote yet, but Aidan's answer fixed the problem.